# Token-based authentication in Horizon HTML Access (Horizon View web-client)

Tags: authentication, virtual-machine, token, vmware, vdi

I'm working on a web application (lets call it Portal) that provides access to Horizon View 6 based virtual desktops using Horizon HTML Access. I want to be able to automatically login users to their machines once they've authenticated in the Portal. Both Portal and VMs are authenticated against the same Active Directory. Is it possible to provide some kind of authentication token to Horizon HTML Access, so that it won't ask users to enter their credentials?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to what you were trying to do?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't.